# Ionic2 Grid with buttons - how can I make buttons in a row together the same height?

Tags: html, css, ionic2

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, I am using a grid that consists of clickable buttons, but some have a lot of text which wraps and makes certain buttons taller. I want to make the corresponding button in the same row fill that vertical space equal to the wrapped button.

Is there a solution here?

```
<ion-grid>

<ion-row class="ionrow">
    <ion-col width-33><button ion-button full>b</button></ion-col>
   <ion-col width-67><button ion-button full></button></ion-col>
</ion-row>

<ion-row class="ionrow">
 <ion-col width-33><button ion-button full>bp</button></ion-col>
 <ion-col width-67><ion-item text-wrap full>Un-aspirated p that sounds like a cross between a b and a p.  Make the <i>bp</i> sound by copying a p sound but not letting any air come out of your mouth.</ion-item></ion-col>
 </ion-row>

 </ion-grid>
```

Comment: Add text-overflow:ellipses to css of element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [column attributes](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Col/).
Try `align-self-stretch`

```
<ion-grid>

<ion-row class="ionrow">
    <ion-col width-33><button ion-button full>b</button></ion-col>
   <ion-col width-67><button ion-button full></button></ion-col>
</ion-row>

<ion-row class="ionrow">
 <ion-col align-self-stretch width-33><button ion-button full>bp</button></ion-col>
 <ion-col width-67><ion-item text-wrap full>Un-aspirated p that sounds like a cross between a b and a p.  Make the <i>bp</i> sound by copying a p sound but not letting any air come out of your mouth.</ion-item></ion-col>
 </ion-row>

 </ion-grid>
```